# How to filter range where at least one cell has red color in excel 2010?

Tags: excel, filter

In excel 2010, how do I filter a rows in a range where at least 1 cell has red color in the row, shown as below:

[image]

Comment: Are you using conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes, conditional formatting.

Comment: What about adding another column that contains the number of cells in the row with red background (you could use a user defined function for that), and then use that column for filtering?

Comment: Right, that will work. thanks. Is it the only way?

Comment: I think you can hardly avoid a helper column, as a filter applied to one column does not know anything about cells in other columns. I was trying to simplify a bit by avoiding a UDF for the helper column with the builtin function `CELL`, but it is not possible either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Answers in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197642/232130), I am moving the comment as an answer.

You can add another column that contains the number of cells in the row with red background (you could use a user defined function for that), and then use that column for filtering.

Plus, I have just found [How to use AutoFilter to filter records based on cell formatting in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213923), which appears to point to what you need instead of a user defined function.